# Validating input parameters for JAX-RS methods

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I'm writing a JAX-RS API, and am using the Response class as the return type of each method. However, I'm trying to figure out the "best" approach to validate parameters.

I've written some REST APIs before, and would usually have custom validation routines in the method and then have a custom return object with validation messages in it. I'm thinking I want to do the same here, but is that "preferred"?

I know there are annotations like `@NotNull`, etc. that you can apply and provide custom validation messages, but I don't really like the way that ends up looking.

So, what I did is that I wrote a return object bean that I'm using as the .entity() for my JAX-RS response, and I'm putting all of my validation messages in there. I use the same return object for Successes and Failures, but it's just a matter of which parameters I populate in there depending on the scenario. This is an internal API, so there won't be any external consumers. I just wanted to standardize the return type so it always returns the same "object".

Does that sound like a good approach? I'm a little rusty on REST API best practices, and I've been googling around like crazy but haven't really come to any best practices conclusions.

Comment: What's the problem with Bean Validation and annotations like `@NotNull`?

Comment: Well, I really want a consistent object to be returned from the API calls regardless of success or failure. If I use the annotations, then that doesn't happen since I do not get to construct my return object.

Answer (score 1):

Input validation for RestAPI is not straight forward. There are a lot of internet resources, but none covers an elegant way of doing this.

As you mentioned the trivial input validations can be done using the annotation of different implementations of jax-rs library. 
These annotations can be sophisticated as regex is supported. Which will help you cover more validation cases than `@NotNull`, `@size` , etc. 
Theses annotations also accept message as input, which will help you customize a message that has to be returned to a user.

Those annotations may not look sexy (specially when regex is involved); but I would still prefer it over writing my own validator.

The other concern of validation which is a little bit tricky is when you want to validate constraints (more like a logic),

say for example you have this requirement:  if parameter A has value X, Parameter B must have not be empty, otherwise it is OK to have parameter B empty. 
This is not something you could handle using the usual  `javax.validation.constraints.*`. I didn't find a good library that could handle this.

take a look at

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolation
```

you could write your own custom validation logic that will be called whenever the library intercepts call to your API.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah, that makes sense. The main concern for me is that I want the return object to always have the same structure, regardless of whether there were failures or if everything completed successfully. I've more worked wth SOAP services before though, so I think that's why I want to do that here. I don't know that doing so is the "right" thing to do for REST APIs, but like you said, there doesn't seem to be a very elegant way.

Comment: as far as your REST API users are concerned what you give as an output is a certain media type (for example JSON or XML), 
it is upto the API consumer to parse and make use of the payload. 
You could for example have an indicator that says the message is a success message or a failure message. 
basing on that the user would expect different kind of structure to parse. 
This is debatable, but personally I would rather keep the two models (success and failure) clean and separate, instead of mixing them to just only use either of them populated at a time.

Comment: and ... as you said, a common entry point could be given to your user, which replies `Response` with certain entity in it, and the entity could be the success or failure model.